# How to get SpeechSynthesis.speak(String) to block?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, text-to-speech, ispeech

```
 public boolean playing=false;
  private void prepareTTSEngine() {
        try {
            synthesis = SpeechSynthesis.getInstance(this);


            synthesis.setSpeechSynthesisEvent(new SpeechSynthesisEvent() {

                public void onPlaySuccessful() {
                    Log.i(TAG, "onPlaySuccessful");
                    playing=true;

                }

                public void onPlayStopped() {
                    Log.i(TAG, "onPlayStopped");
                    playing=false;

                }

                public void onPlayFailed(Exception e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "onPlayFailed");
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    playing=false;
                }

                public void onPlayStart() {
                    Log.i(TAG, "onPlayStart");
                    //playing=true;

                }

                @Override
                public void onPlayCanceled() {
                    Log.i(TAG, "onPlayCanceled");
                    playing=false;
                }


            });

            //synthesis.setVoiceType("usenglishfemale1"); // All the values available to you can be found in the developer portal under your account

        } catch (InvalidApiKeyException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Invalid API key\n" + e.getStackTrace());
            Toast.makeText(_context, "ERROR: Invalid API key", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }

         prepareTTSEngine();
        String speech= MapLocationOverlay.mSelectedMapLocation.getShortDesc();
        synthesis.setVoiceType("usenglishfemale");

        BreakIterator iterator = BreakIterator.getSentenceInstance(Locale.US);
        iterator.setText(speech);
        int start = iterator.first();

        for (int end = iterator.next();end != BreakIterator.DONE; start = end, end = iterator.next()) {
            if(speech !=null && speech.substring(start,end).compareTo("")!=0)
            {
                String sentence_next=speech.substring(start,end);                   
                        //set ready flag to true (so isReady returns true) 


                while(playing==true)
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                            try {
                                synthesis.speak(sentence_next);
                            } catch (BusyException e) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            } catch (NoNetworkException e) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }


enter code here


            }
        }
    }
```

`I'm using [the iSpeech library's`SpeechSynthesis`class](http://www.ispeech.org/androidsdkdoc/com/ispeech/SpeechSynthesis.html). When I call the`speak`method in a`for`-loop, passing one sentence at a time, all of the sentences start at once. I guess this is because the method is non-blocking. It's not open-source, so I can't see how it works. How can I make it so that it doesn't start one sentence until the previous sentence is done?

Comment: No code, poorly worded question, no effort put into it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually with those kinds of libraries, the code doesn't wait for the sound to stop playing (for good reasons).

From the [documentation of your library](http://www.ispeech.org/bbsdkdoc/com/iSpeech/SpeechSynthesis.SpeechSynthesisEvent.html), it seems that you should listen for `SpeechSynthesisEvent` with `PLAY_SUCCESSFUL` before reading the next sentence.

If it suits your needs the `javax.speech.synthesis` has a rather simple mechanism to wait until the speech is done, check it out: http://java.sun.com/products/java-media/speech/forDevelopers/jsapi-guide/Synthesis.html

Comment: Thanks for attention. But i'm writing Android app, so I cannot use javax.speech, javax.speech.synthesis libraries. and I cannot use waitenginestate method.